# .NET 4.x complains about deserialization of non-public properties as opposed to .NET 3.5 - how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-3.5

I upgraded the unity scripting runtime of my project from .Net 3.5 to 4.x. At runtime, when it comes to deserializing an XML file, it gives me the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot deserialize type
>   'xxxxxx.Module.Impl.WebModule' **because it contains property
>   'wellConfig' which has no public setter.**
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetSettableMembers
>   (System.Xml.Serialization.StructMapping mapping,
>   System.Collections.ArrayList list)

This is the related property:

```
[XmlElement("WebWellConfiguration")]
public WebWellConfiguration wellConfig { get; protected set; }
```

When I remove the 'protected' access modifier, the error goes away, and the deserialization is successful, but I don't want to do that.

- Why did unity scripting runtime 3.5 have no issue with the deserialization of a non-public setter, but 4.x fails to do so?
- How to fix the problem without removing the protected or private access modifier?

Comment: `protected set` means that it can only be assigned a value *by the class or its children.* Serialization is almost always done via an external class. Your choices are: (a) `public set` or (b) `[NonSerialized]`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a `private` backing field using [`[SerializeField]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) instead

```
[XmlElement("WebWellConfiguration")] 
// [SerializeField] allows to mark private fields for serialization
[SerializeField] private WebWellConfiguration wellConfig;

// since this is now no longer an auto-property but
// using a backing field this one won't be serialized at all
public WebWellConfiguration WellConfig 
{ 
    get { return wellConfig; } 
    protected set { wellConfig = value; }
}
```

One more bonus side-effect of doing this: You now also should be able to see and configure this field via the Unity Inspector!

---

*Assuming of course `WebWellConfiguration` is `[Serializable]` already anyway .. otherwise it wouldn't be able to be (de)serialized at all.*

Comment: Thank but this code till leads to the same error. By the way, why to use [SerializeField]? The class containing this property is not MonoBehaviour.

Comment: yes but the class is hopefully `[Serializable]` otherwise it shouldn't be able to serialize it **at all**. `[SerializeField]` doesn't only apply to `MonoBehaviour` but to any class that is `[Serializable]`.

Comment: Try again now .. the field's naming of course has to match your data otherwise the deserializer again tries to write the property itself. You might have to fix the name though in other scripts using that property now.

Comment: I tried again (copy-pasting your code) and still got the same error message.